# Creating tables and displaying without RAD components

Tags: database, delphi, tquery

My job gave me a challenge to do the following... I am still a rookie and learning as fast as I can but I have this curve ball and can't quite get my mind to it.

If it is not to much trouble... how can I create, modify and display Tables with the below exceptions?

RAD is out. No dataset, query or table components of any kind. For example, don’t use : DataSource, DataSet, DBGrid, DBText, DBEdit etc.) A connection component like TADOConnection is acceptable.

Comment: No RAD components? Do you perhaps mean no data-aware components? That is components that have `DB` in their names and have a `DataSource` property? Can you for example use a TEdit instead of a TDBEdit? If you can't use a TDataSet descendant such as for example a TADOQuery, then TADOConnection is pretty much useless and I really don't understand the point of the exercise. If they are simply excluding all data-aware _controls_ then they are basically asking you to decouple the visual presentation from the data access one. Look/google for information on separating application layers.

Comment: onyly the following has to be excluded... DataSource, DataSet, DBGrid, DBText, DBEdit. everything else can be used

Comment: Sounds like someone has no clue about what he is taklking. While the others do make sense in certain cases, TDataSet and TDataSource (as they are used for master-detail and lookup purposes) don't belong into that group. If you cannot use TDataSet then you may be better to use another tool or quit that job.

Comment: @UweRaabe: you can do without TDataSource that is only needed to connect data-aware controls to a TDataset descendant. But I do agree that you need a TDataSet descendant of some sort or you will really be engaged in a futile exercise. Master Detail can be implemented without Data Sources as well. You just need to do the sync'ing yourself then

Comment: @MarjanVenema, TDataSource is also used to connect a detail table to its master and to connect lookup fields to its lookup sources.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind that might get away without all these components is using an ORM framework.

Comment: I have to write my own classes, suppose to be a simple test, does it make sense now... so I have to code all of those without using the "EASY" way

Comment: @UweRaabe: Ah, yes, that is another use, though in my own code I just used my framework to do this kind of stuff without TDataSource. I think he is indeed being asked to develop a simple ORM framework or in the first instance just all the classes he needs and then abstract a framework from that.

Comment: can I mail win32 app spec to you... maybe it will make more sense!

Comment: How about asking questions that are clear and make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ADOConnection.Execute` Method to fetch data from a query and then iterate and display in some sort of manner, e.g. using a TStringGrid or the famous TVirtualTreeView

Comment: I have created the database, but I need to create 2 tables and link them to each other, "a basic phonebook" one table holds customer and one holds phone number, that is where I get stuck, dont know how to add entries to this database without DBGrid and those "easy" tools

Comment: You can `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` any table without the need of datasensitive controls. You can use the `ADOConnection.Execute` method for DML as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use adoconnection, you can probably use the ADOQuery component.

Then you get something like this:

```
sl.Clear;
ADOQuery.Close;
try
  ADOQuery.SQL.Text:='SELECT names FROM phonebook';
  ADOQuery.Open;
  While not ADOQuery.Eof do begin
    sl.Add(AdoQuery.FieldByName('names').AsString);
    ADOQuery.Next;
  end;
finally
  ADOQuery.Close;
end;
```

or:

```
ADOQuery.Close;
try
  ADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO phonebook (name,number)VALUES'+QuotedStr(NameString) +',' + QuotedStr(numberstring) +')'
  ADOQuery.ExecSQL;
finally
  ADOQuery.Close;
end;
```

(this uses non-parameterized queries, using parameterized queries is ofcourse better.)